# Model in Module In Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I was just creating a form in prestashop.So, I need to store the data from ront in end in the database. Please anyone tell me how to implement Models in module or for module. As I was enable to find any related article regarding this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at one of the default modules provided by prestashop. Take an  example that creates a form in front. Then  look at how the view of that specific model was created and how was data treated via controller.

examples: blockserach, blockmanufacturer..